Did Queen (or Freddie Mercury) really not like Star Wars?
The song "Bicycle Race" by Queen has the following lyrics;

You say black, I say white
You say bark, I say bite
You say shark, I say hey man
Jaws was never my scene
And I don't like Star Wars

I know not everyone has to like Star Wars, but is this true, or just fit rhythmically for the song?
Has Mercury or another member of the band commented on the lyrics in an interview, documentary, or apperance?

Or maybe those are just the two biggest movies of the 1970s when the song was written?

Next you'll tell me he also didn't just kill a man

Exactly as @Plutor points out, it is very confused to confuse the character in a song or novel with the writer.

This very issue has been addressed by Brian May. According to him, Freddie Mercury liked Star Wars, and Bicycle Race was not meant to be autobiographical. Verbatim from The Official Brian May Website, posted 29th May 2011.

[Brian was asked if Freddie didn’t like Star Wars, or was this just for sake of the lyrics of ‘Bicycle Race’ – see LETTERS]
Well, it’s a fair question, I guess. But did you ever read ‘MobyDick’ ? I always remember the first words were “Call me Ishmael”. But of course Herman Melville wasn’t Ishmael. As with a novel, just because a song is written in the first person doesn’t mean it’s in any way autobiographical. As I remember, Freddie liked Star Wars a lot, and he actually wasn’t very keen on riding his bicycle (if he even had one!) – he preferred being driven in a Rolls Royce! But he created a character in the song, and this character can say what he wants, and he can ride his bicycle where he likes!
Cheers
Bri

Moreover, there is photographical record of Queen incorporating Darth Vader impersonators in some live coreographies, at least on 10th August 1980 in Houston, Texas. Specifically Freddie Mercury rode on Darth Vader's shoulders. See TheStrut.com.

He's being awfully charitable to say "it's a fair question", imo. Does anyone (who's not a child) really think that lyricists must be writing about themselves when they use the word "I" ??

@AakashM Well, implying some agreement with the content of a song is common, and some artists make a point of doing so.

@AakashM They weren't asking whether a lyric like this must reflect the lyricist's personal opinion, but merely whether it happens to do so in this particular case. Of course that's a fair question.

For future commentators: there is no point in telling me whether you believe the question was sound or not. If you want to say "The question is stupid" or "The question is great", please comment on the question, as that is not relevant to my answer. For that matter, I've already said my piece on what I believe the issues to investigate were.

I'm not sure Freddie or the others were even into bikes. Tour de France just happened to pass Montreux when Queen were there recording and I guess they got inspired.

And similarly to "don't like Star Wars" there's lyrics from More of That Jazz from the same album (written by Roger Taylor not Freddie) saying "Only football gives us thrills. Rock 'n' roll just pays the bills." Now I don't think that was true either :) That song is simply about being uninspired and moody, not to be taken as a literal statement either.

@Amarth The quote I gave contains Brian May's assessment of Freddie Mercury's taste in matters of urban transportation.

@Amarth Your argument about Tour de France is a prime example of using information not as a source, but as validation of a bias. Brian May said that Freddie Mercury didn't like bicycles, therefore when you read that Bicycle Race was inspired by Tour the France you say: "Well, of curse they didn't give a crap about bicycles and wrote a song about a sports event!". If he had said that Freddie Mercury liked bicycles, you would have said: "Well, of course! He even wrote a song about Tour de France!". In truth, the latter would have been the most resonable hypothesis, absent information.

@AakashM I counter with all of Taylor Swift's songs that relate to .. Taylor Swift

@Gae.S. Yeah but Freddie didn't write all songs on the album so the bike part is a bit taken out of context. Most famously Bicycle Race and Fat Bottomed Girls (written by May even) reference each other and bikes, but even more tracks on the same record contain bicycle references. So this would be some silly thing the whole band agreed to include on the record.

@Gae.S. And there's no bias. Fact remains that the album Jazz contains bike references in at least 3-4 songs and official sources say this is because Tour the France passed through Montreux as Queen were recording. If anything it sounds as if they were struggling with inspiration, regardless of their bike preferences.

In addition to the excellent answer by Gae. S. the point of this verse is to show the contrarian nature of the protagonist; "You say black, I say white", etc.
The two films mentioned were hugely successful films of the era, so saying he doesn't like them goes contrary to the maintream view and emphasises this contrariness.

That was basically my point, but you say it better.  Props! :)
